# How to check users inputed string is in the array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I want my user type a string in input box of html,than i want to check if it is in the array of items or not.I am using this JS code:

```js
var items = ["apple"];
var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;

function lol() {
  document.write(items.includes(userInput));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="lol()">check</button>
```

But when i run this every time it gives `false`.

Comment: Welcome!
`document.getElementById("input")` is a "live" reference,
`document.getElementById("input").value` is not.
Remove `.value` from global variable, and
Add it to `includes`: `includes(userInput.value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

into the function, because it assigns the value at start and is never changing.

```js
var items = ["apple"];

function lol() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(items.includes(userInput));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="lol()">check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the error. This is my code -

```
var items = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango'];

var input = 'apple';

console.log(items.includes('apple'));
```

It works as expected. The problem is that you have called the lol() function in the button. So, the function is called when the page loads and not when it is clicked. Another thing is that you have to move the line in which you get user input into the lol() function.

Comment: See my comment for where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onChange event listener for the input field and change the userInput value for every change in the input field.

```js
var items = ["apple"];
var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
function onChangeUserInput (event) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
   userInput = event.target.value;
}

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('change', onChangeUserInput);


function lol() {
  document.write(items.includes(userInput));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="lol()">check</button>
```